# JQUERY How to hide div inside inframes

Tags: jquery, iframe

I would like to hide the ads over the videoplayer
http://www.onlinetvportal.eu/rtlklub
How can I reach div#ads_back div#ads_front with Jquery?

There are a lot of iframe :(
a part of dom look likes so:
... > #yibix_player >  html > body > iframe > html > body > #playercont > iframe > html > body > #yibix_player > html > body > iframe > html > body > div#ads_back

Answer (score 1):

```
    DO it in javascript
<div id="ads_back">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("ads_back").style.display = "none";
    </script>
```

Comment: "document.getElementById("ads_back").style.display = "none";"

Does not work inside iframes     :(


<iframe>
      <iframe>
            <iframe>
                   <div id="ads_back">